# I want the notification to get closed after I opened the app

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I get a notification when a task is done on my app.I have a Reminder app. So when I get the notification I click on the notification which is in the notiftication status bar,and it works perfectly,the notification is erased and it`s opened the app.The problem is when I get the notification and if I ignore it and go directly by clicking on the app  (not in the notification status bar),the app is opened but the notification is still there in the notification status bar.What should be done here in the code,to erase the notification when I click on the app??

Answer (score 2):

```
NotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()**

Comment: i`ve edited my question,can u show me what to do in this code?

Answer (score 2):

First you need the notification id - you should know its id, since you created the notification.
Once you have it, you would call [NotificationManager.cancel(id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29):

```
NotificationManager notifManager = ... // get the instance
notifManager.cancel(notificationId);
```

Comment: i`ve edited the question,can u take a look and tell me what to do in this code?